# response 503 python requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, http-status-code-503

hi I trying to get a request to https://www.playerup.com/ with blow code :

```
import requests
header = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36"}
r = requests.get("https://www.playerup.com/",headers=header)
print(r.status_code)
```

but it give me a [503]type error 
I trying timeout for 5 second and also not work 
how I should fix it ?

Comment: What 503 tells you?

Comment: how should I fine it ?
when I trying with Chrome, it's fine 
but in code I don't know 
I'm beginner man

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So times using a referer and google cache can help you avoid these failures. So your code should be:

```
# here added a referer
header = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36" ,'referer':'https://www.google.com/'}
# now use a google cache
r = requests.get("http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:www.playerup.com/",headers=header)
```

Now see the status code:

```
>>>r
<Response [200]>
```